# Setting up as a Windows shared hosting provider

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, shared-hosting

Is there a convenient software package available for setting up and managing shared web hosting (PHP/IIS/MySQL/FTP) within Windows?

Features I need:

- Isolation (as best as possible anyway on a shared server) so that it is impossible, or at least difficult, for one account to write to the directories of another
- Simple set up of a new account/site
- A control panel for users of the service would be nice, but not required

This is not for a commercial environment... just a large organization that happens to host websites for other organizations once in awhile.  Resources are slim, so virtualization is a bit out of the scope of this project.  I am hoping something exists to handle the setup of these sites, and the appropriate permissions on directories.

Billing features are not necessary, but it wouldn't be a problem if they were built in.

The software doesn't have to be free, but that is always a plus.

Any advice you can give would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we are going to end up going with [Enkompass](http://www.cpanel.net/windows/overview.html).

[image: Enkompass Screen Shot]

Seems to be basically cPanel for Windows, which is what I'm looking for.  I haven't tested it out yet, but they do offer 30-day trial licenses.  I will probably build a box and get it running next week.